# Evaluate combinations of page dimensions

Tags: margins, calculations, lengths, page

For any given class and its specified page layout, I'd like to be able to combine (sum or subtract) a subset of the page dimensions, to obtain a length to work with, without specifying absolute values.

For example: I'd like to set the width of a figure equal to `\textwidth` + `\marginparsep` + `\marginparwidth`

I don't have a MWE yet, because I'm trying to figure out if this is possible somehow.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355289/putting-a-figure-into-textwidth-marginparsep-marginparwidth) is related, but applicable only to KOMA

Comment: Where is the problem? \dimexpr \textwidth +\marginparsep\relax should work fine.

Comment: thanks! I also figured out `\newlength\widthw
\setlength{\widthw}{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}`

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin yes either works, but note your version requires the `calc` package Ulrike's version uses (e)tex primitive arithmetic  so does not need any particular packages.

Comment: "This" does apply to KOMA-Script, but not a KOMA-Script class. Package `scrextend` exists and can be used with several other classes, e.g, the standard classes. So the example there does also work, e.g., with `\documentclass{book}\usepackage{scrextend}`.

Comment: it's always nice to learn some primitives, and not to have load a package just for one purpose :)