# How to make full use of paper margin

Tags: margins, subplot

I have a five pics presented on one page. I find that the pics are so small I want to magnify them. But when I use larger `\linewidth` in the `\includegraphics`, pics are overlapped together. I think the best way is to move the (a)(c) a little bit left and the (b)(d) a little bit right. Then I have the space to zoom them. Is there any method? Thanks for your helping.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear0001.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
    \end{subfigure}
\qquad 
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear001.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:penaltyh method}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear01.eps}
\caption{}
\label{fig:hard_cokntact}
\end{subfigure}
    \qquad 
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear03.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:penaltyh method}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear05.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please let us know if you use the `subcaption` or the `subfig` package.

Comment: Not clear on zooming in the extra space. Can you add an image of the page layout as per your need.

Comment: It looks like you are using TeX's default page layout, which was originally intended to be used with the Journal of the American Mathematical Society's 7″ x 10″ pages, and produces very large margins on either "letter"-sized or A4 paper.  Consider adding `\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry}` or `\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}` to the preamble of your document, depending on which size paper you intend to print on.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you make the following changes:

- Change all five instances of `\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}` to `\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}`. This will make the graphs wider.
- Change all five instances of `[width=1.2\linewidth]` to `[width=1\linewidth]`. This will get rid of the overlaps within each row.
- Replace both instances of `\qquad` with `\hfill`.
- Optional: Delete (or comment out) all instances of `\centering` except the very first one.
- Optional: Provide for a bit of vertical whitespace between the rows, by inserting `\medskip` (or `\bigskip`) instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    %%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear0001.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    %%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear001.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:penaltyh method}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
%%\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear01.eps}
\caption{}
\label{fig:hard_cokntact}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    %%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear03.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:penaltyh method}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    %%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{images/energy_ratio/linear05.eps}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm - oh no! :-( fixed now...

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to [Mico's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488181/9057) you can indeed use (parts of) the page margins, if you need. KOMA-Script provides an environment `addmargin` to increase or decrease the current margins of an area. If you do not use a KOMA-Script class you can use package `scrextend` as shown here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,scrextend}

\usepackage{showframe}% only to illustrate the page areas

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{addmargin}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[page=1,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[page=2,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:penaltyh method}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[page=3,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[page=4,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:penaltyh method}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[page=5,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:hard_cokntact}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{addmargin}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image: five ducks partly in the margin]

There are other packages, that provide similar environments.

See also, e.g.:

- [putting a figure into \textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355289/9057)
- [How to center wide subfigures in classicthesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466083/9057)